# Difference between scanf("%79[^\n]",line); vs scanf("%79[^\n]\n",line) vs scanf("%79[^\n]s",line)

Tags: c, scanf

I was writing a program in c to read the contents of a file.
The code is as follows:

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   void main()
   {
   char line[90];
   while(scanf("%79[^\n]\n",line)==1) 
   printf("%s",line);
   }
```

The above code reads a file content and displays it on the screen.

But

```
while(scanf("%79[^\n]",line)==1) and while(scanf("%79[^\n]s",line)==1) or while(scanf("%79[^\n]s\n",line)==1)
```

doesn't work.(They display only the first line)

Can anyone explain?

Comment: The first one is for accepting input of type 'string'

Comment: @shekhar suman...all of them are accepting strings

Comment: `%79[^\n]` is the format string, does not need to be post-fixed with `s`. The second newline `%79[^\n]\n` literally moves to the next line

Comment: I think the mini-regex `[^\n]` takes the place of the `s` format specifier. The others will match if you have a literal s at the end of a line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format `"%79[^\n]"` says all the characters up to 79 characters max that are not `'\n'`.

When you use,

```
scanf("%79[^\n]s",line)
```

the return value should not be 1 since the `s` in the format specifier expects a literal `s` after it has finished reading all the characters that are not `'\n'`. In other words, `scanf` reports failure.

When you use,

```
scanf("%79[^\n]\n",line)
```

it succeeds because it finds a literal `'\n'` at the end.

The difference between

```
scanf("%79[^\n]",line)
```

and

```
scanf("%79[^\n]\n",line)
```

is that the `'\n'` is left in the input stream in the first case while it is consumed in the second case. In the second case, not only is the `'\n'` consumed but any sequence of whitespaces starting at the `'\n'` is consumed too (Thanks to @MattMcNabb for the additional clarification).

If you want `scanf` to consume just the `'\n'`, use:

```
scanf("%79[^\n]%*c",line)
```

Comment: Note that `\n`, outside the square brackets, matches *any sequence of whitespace*, not just a single newline. This version will also eat any leading whitespace on the following line.

Comment: "the return value should not be 1" is mis-leading.  With `scanf("%79[^\n]s",line)` if any 1 to 79 `char` are scanned into `line`, `scanf()` will return 1.  The matching or not matching of a literal `'s'` does not affect the `scanf()` result.

Comment: Like-wise `scanf("%79[^\n]\n",line)` returns 1 should it scan anything into `line`.  Finding (or not finding) a following `"\n"' does not change the return value of `scanf()`.  The `"\n"' does affect the consumption of white-space after scanning in `line`.

Comment: Certain you want `scanf("%79[^\n]*c",line)` --> `scanf("%79[^\n]%*c",line)`

Answer (score 1):

Since the format itself is the same, the key to solving this is, as you can certainly tell, the trailing character after the format string (or the absence of that character)

- When you put `'\n'` at the end, you tell `scanf` to read and ignore the end-of-line character after reading the string. This works fine, because `'\n'` is what terminates the string in accordance with your format (i.e. `%79[^\n]`).
- When you put an `'s'` at the end, you tell `scanf` that you expect a literal `s` after the string that ends in `'\n'`. This is an error, because `scanf` will read the string up to, and excluding, the `'\n'` character* .
- When you do not put `'\n'` at the end, the first read will succeed, but all subsequent ones will stumble upon the `'\n'`, and stop reading right away.

Note that the code that works may produce unexpected results for input strings that exceed 79 characters. These strings would be chopped at the 79-character mark, their remainder presented as the beginning of the next string.

*  There is an unlikely situation when this read would succeed - namely, when the read terminates due to reaching the limit of 79, *and* then discovering the letter `s` at the 80-th space.

Comment: I think the line length issue could be fixed by `while ( scanf("%79[^\n]%*[^\n]", line) ) { getchar(); printf("%s\n", line); }`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Ah, I see your point - you are right, this would fix the problem with splitting long lines. Thank you!

Comment: @Matt McNabb Note: `scanf("%79[^\n]%*[^\n]"` gets stuck if the first `char` is `'\n'`.  It also consumes multiple `'\n'` which may/may not be OK.

Comment: Suggest edit: "`'\n'` at the end, you tell scanf to read and ignore all consecutive end-of-line characters (and any other white-space) after reading the string"

Comment: @chux It doesn't consume multiple newlines, and `\n` at the end would be bad as then it consumes other whitespace at the start of the next line. However you are right that `scanf` returns `0` if the `[]` matched an empty string.

Comment: updated version: `while( line[0] = 0, scanf("%79[^\n]%*[^\n]",line), getchar() != EOF ) printf("%s\n", line);`  .

Comment: @Matt McNabb  Agreed "It doesn't consume multiple newlines", though it was `scanf("%79[^\n]%*[\n]"`.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of subtle differences:

1) `"%79[^\n]"` tells `scanf()` to scan and save 1 to 79 `char` except `'\n'`.  If the first `char` attempted to scan is `\n`, *nothing* will be save and scanning stops.  In OP's examples, 0 is returned.  Else a `'\0'` is append to the destination `line`.  A 1 is returned if there is nothing more.

2) `"%79[^\n]\n"` does 1) and if successful continues to look for *any* consecutive white-space, not just `'\n'`.  This will typically include a `'\n'` *and* then all leading whitespace of the *next* line.  It will return 1 regardless if it find a white-space.

3) `"%79[^\n]s"` does 1 and if successful continues to look a single `s`. It will return 1 regardless if it find a `s`.  Likely this is not OP's desire - drop the `'s'`.

4) `"%79[^\n]s\n"` does 3) and if successful, behaves like 2) continues to look for *any* consecutive white-space, not just `'\n'`.  It will return 1 regardless if it find a white-space.

5) The 3 `while()` statement is fairly complex, taken as a whole.  It gets stuck trying to read a `'\n'` into the beginning of 1 of the 3 `scanf()`.

A better approach, if code needs to use `scanf()` to read a line, is
`while (scanf(" %79[^\n]%*c", line) ==1)`.  This will toss leading white-space and then read a line up to `'\n'`, tossing that `'\n'` via the `"%*c"`.

The best approach is to use `fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)`.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the problem is concested to logic values shortcircuting.
ie. when compiler determents that he has sufficient information to evaluate the whole expression it doesn't need to test other logic values(and doesn't evaluate them).

i.e. false and call_foo() always evaluate to false, so call_foo() is never called.

It could also be connected to that, when you read a line in scanf(first of 3 logic expresions) others scanf will read on next lines, not that same lines, because the first scanf already had taken the data from the buffer.